# Как выполнить валидацию по клику MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf

Первоначально при запуске TextBox пустой, если я начинаю в нем что то печатать, а потом удаляю все, чтобы он был пустой, то появляется ошибка валидации. Но мне бы хотелось, чтобы эта ошибка появлялась и при нажатии на кнопку (если в TextBox  совсем ничего не было напичатано). Мне не понятно, что нужно написать в Command или CanExecute, чтобы заставить TextBox запустить валидацию.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ExpenseTracker.Views.AccountsView"
         x:ClassModifier="internal"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:validationRules="clr-namespace:ExpenseTracker.ValidationResultRules">
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="accountName">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Input" 
                     Mode="TwoWay" 
                     UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <validationRules:NotEmpty></validationRules:NotEmpty>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>

    <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2"
            Command="{Binding AddAccountCommand}">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), ElementName=accountName}" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style> Add Account
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

```
internal sealed class NotEmpty :ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        ValidationResult result = ValidationResult.ValidResult;

        if(((string)value).Length==0)
        {
            result = new ValidationResult(false, "String is empty");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле использовать `ValidationRule` в MVVM неправильно, потому что это всё-таки вьюшная валидация и VM о ней ничего не знает. Вам же нужна валидация в VM, которая реализуется с помощью интерфейсов `IDataErrorInfo`/`INotifyDataErrorInfo` (см. [этот ответ на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9950236/6766879)).

"Малой кровью" вашу задачу можно решить включив в правиле валидации `ValidatesOnTargetUpdated`:

```
...
<validationRules:NotEmpty ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
...
```

В правиле валидации только измените условие на такое (может ведь и null придти):

```
...
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value))
...
```

Тогда ваш TextBox будет красным прямо при запуске

Еще вариант (который я нашел [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17102866/6766879)), написать такой класс для принудительной валидации:

```
public static class Validator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This method forces WPF to validate the child controls of the control passed in as a parameter.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parent">Type: DependencyObject. The control which is the descendent root control to validate.</param>
    /// <returns>Type: bool. The validation result</returns>
    public static bool IsValid(DependencyObject parent)
    {
        // Validate all the bindings on the parent
        bool valid = true;
        LocalValueEnumerator localValues = parent.GetLocalValueEnumerator();
        while (localValues.MoveNext())
        {
            LocalValueEntry entry = localValues.Current;
            if (BindingOperations.IsDataBound(parent, entry.Property))
            {
                Binding binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(parent, entry.Property);
                foreach (ValidationRule rule in binding.ValidationRules)
                {
                    ValidationResult result = rule.Validate(parent.GetValue(entry.Property), null);
                    if (!result.IsValid)
                    {
                        BindingExpression expression = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(parent, entry.Property);
                        Validation.MarkInvalid(expression, new ValidationError(rule, expression, result.ErrorContent, null));
                        valid = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Validate all the bindings on the children
        for (int i = 0; i != VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); ++i)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            if (!IsValid(child))
            {
                valid = false;
            }
        }
        return valid;
    }
}
```

И использовать его, например, при загрузке окна:

```
Loaded += (s, e) => Validator.IsValid(this);
```

Или в обработчике клика по кнопке.

Правда, как взаимодействовать с ним из VM я не знаю (почему — см. первый абзац ответа).